# SVG to HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Well I have an SVG file named `7.svg`.

How can I display the image with HTML or CSS in my `index.html`?

Comment: The first hit when Googling "HTML SVG" leads to a useful result. Just sayin'

Comment: its okay :) , yeah it gives results, i googled also, but i think i googled with too advanced terms like: svg image import with css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can do this in three different ways.

**Using the `<embed>` Tag**

```
<embed src="7.svg" width="300" height="100"
type="image/svg+xml"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
```

**Using the `<object>` Tag**

```
<object data="7.svg" width="300" height="100"
type="image/svg+xml"
codebase="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
```

**Using the `<iframe>` Tag**

```
<iframe src="7.svg" width="300" height="100">
</iframe>
```

Tell me which one works out for you. Please run it on differnt browsers and let me know.

HTML 5 info:

Since your are using HTML 5 you probably wanna check out this: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#svg
Its still under work and is partially implemented in Firefox, Safari, Opera (xhtml5 serialization only)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/svg_in_html_introduction

Comment: all worked except iframe was bad, it made a visible weird frame around it

Comment: the border around the iframe can easily be removed with some css `iframe { border: 0 }`

Comment: You forgot the `<img>` tag, and the ability to copy/paste directly as [`<svg>` in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml).

Comment: [Adobe SVG viewer](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/mainframed.html) was released almost 10 years ago, last updated 6 years ago, and officially [discontinued](http://www.adobe.com/svg/eol.html) over 2 years ago. This is not the way to embed SVG.

Comment: [ie6](http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/ie/ie6/default.mspx)released 10 years ago and officially [discontinued](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps/#Internet_Explorer) over 4 years ago. It is not the right browser to use!

Answer (score 1):

Add this somehwere in your html file

```
<embed src="7.svg" width="300" height="100"
type="image/svg+xml"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
```

taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp)

Comment: Ugh; [Adobe SVG viewer](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/mainframed.html) was released almost 10 years ago, last updated 6 years ago, and officially [discontinued](http://www.adobe.com/svg/eol.html) over 2 years ago. W3Schools is almost always a _terrible_ source for information. Please do not cite them, and see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`<img>` tags support SVG. Just add `<img src="/path/to/svg.svg">` to the page.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/evx5696v/1/).
[image: Image of Tux]

Take control of the size with CSS.

Comment: Hey it is converting it to another format... let me try that again. svg works.

Comment: Ok, *now* if you inspect the image in the answer, you will see that it is an `img` tag with `src` referring to the SVG file directly.